# DBOpenRequest events do not fire

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

I'm struggling with opening indexed db. Here is my code:

```
var db;

window.onload = function()
{    
  window.indexedDB = window.indexedDB || window.mozIndexedDB 
                                      || window.webkitIndexedDB 
                                      || window.msIndexedDB;

  var DBOpenRequest = window.indexedDB.open("test", 1);
    
  DBOpenRequest.onerror = function(event)
  {
     console.log("DBOpenRequest.onerror");
  };
    
  DBOpenRequest.onsuccess = function(event)
  {
    console.log("DBOpenRequest.onsuccess");
    db = DBOpenRequest.result;
  };
    
  DBOpenRequest.onupgradeneeded = function(event)
  {
    console.log("DBOpenRequest.onupgradeneeded");
  };
};
```

but none of the event fire. All DBOpenRequest properties set to null except for readyState set to "done" and result set to IDBDatabase object.

What is missing here so I could access indexdb via db variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You do not need to wait for the browser to fire the load event. indexedDB readiness is not related to DOM readiness. You can simply call indexedDB.open in the global scope and it will eventually execute.
2. You probably do not need the statement where you check for the vendor prefixes. Prefixes have generally been dropped. Just use window.indexedDB and delete this statement.
3. You should also listen for the blocked event. This event generally fires when opening the same page in multiple tabs around the same time. When blocked the other events will not fire.
4. The line `db = DBOpenRequest.result` appears to be assigning a value (the instance of an IDBDatabase object) that is only valid within the scope of the function to a variable defined in an outer scope where it is no longer valid. This signals a lack of experience with writing and using async code. You should probably learn more about async code before continuing.

Comment: Are you sure about point 4? Copying the db instance out of the onsuccess handler is something I've done before w/ IDB with no problem. I used the event value though not DBOpenRequest, but shouldn't it work fine?

Comment: I am sure about 4. It will sometimes work fine, but not always, and is a code smell. Basically, you are exploiting and taking a risk when you do it. It is an acceptable risk, but only if you know what you are doing, and can debug the issues it will eventually cause. I assume someone asking this type of question does not and cannot.

Comment: So let me ask you this then - how do you handle doing ad hoq queries later? Do you put all those calls within the onsuccess handler? How do you work with the db globally?

Comment: Also - do you have proof (in the spec maybe?) that the db object returned in onsuccess can't be used again? As I've said - I've never had issues with it. I'm not sure how it is code smell either, but we can agree to disagree on that.

Comment: Probably outside the scope of the question, and again would be a long answer. Briefly, I open a connection as needed to do later queries. The calls are all within each connection success handler. I do not use a global db variable. In the spec (http://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB), indexedDB.open is async.

Comment: Just because .open is async does not mean we can't keep a handle to the db later though. I'm not sure you are right about this - but as you said - we're going off scope.

Comment: Josh, as an FYI, I posted this to the IDB google group. It is *super* low volume, but I figured it would be a better place to discuss it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, for one, in onsuccess, the db comes from the event, not the original object:

```
db = event.target.result;
```

Most likely you got this as an error in your console.

Comment: event.target.result === DBOpenRequest.result

Comment: Oh Interesting - thanks. Didn't know it updated the original request object - but that makes sense.